# How to access the data in QT plaintextedit?

Tags: qt

I'm working on this small program for my Robotics team and I came across I problem where I have no idea on how to access the data from the plain text edit box that the user uses to insert additional comments. I was thinking it be:

```
ui->addcomments->_________;
```

But I looked through the entire class and found nothing remotely close to something that returns a string containing the comment. I want to take the comments and store it in an array or a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `toPlainText()` method Will help you to retrieve your data then use `clear()` to remove the text from the GUI.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I was right. But now I have this problem where the compiler is telling me that it can't convert the Qstring data toPlainText() returns into string. But I'm not sure how to change the initial data type to QString. Replacing std::string with Qstring does not do the trick.

Comment: to convert the result to std string you need to use `QString::toStdString()`

Comment: QString provides you a toStdString() method to get a std::string does it help ?

Comment: It worked! But I'm trying to figure out this annoying error. It's giving me an error at:
    void Scouting::on_button10_toggled(bool checked)

The error message: "checked" unreferenced formal parameter. I didn't get this with previous compiling, but all of a sudden this pops up.

Comment: In fact it is not an error, it should be e warning. It's because you do not use the "checked" parameter. To avoid it, replace (bool checked) by (bool). 
Pls make your question resolved on this post to help other people who could ask the same question.